# Underscore.js template with Backbone.js error

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, underscore.js

The line below is completely failing.

```
template: _.template($('#test').html()),
```

Trying to follow a simple example from https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jquerymobile to use jQuery mobile along with Backbone.js. The error I'm getting in the web inspector is: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'str.replace') which is in line 913 of the underscore.js. Using is _.template in this fashion:

```
template: _.template("<h1>To Do</h1>"),
```

works, but in order to incorporate the jQuery mobile styles, that way won't do.

todo.js

```
TodoBb.Views.ComCentersTodo = Backbone.View.extend({

template: _.template($('#test').html()),


render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
}
});
```

main.html

```
<script type = 'text/template' id = 'test'> <h1>To Do</h1> </script>
```

Comment: So whats the problem? Is the jQuery mobile styles not appearing? For that you need to trigger the create event like `$("...").trigger("create")`, tho just looking at the docs now, I cant find the create event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM isn't ready when your view is being parsed:

```
TodoBb.Views.ComCentersTodo = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#test').html()),
    //...
});
```

so `$('#test').html()` is `null` and you're actually doing this:

```
TodoBb.Views.ComCentersTodo = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(null),
    //...
});
```

The internals of [`_.template`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) while converting the template to a JavaScript function.

You have a few options:

1. Put the `TodoBd.Views.ComCentersTodo` definition inside a `$(document).ready()` handler:

   ```
   $(function() {
       TodoBb.Views.ComCentersTodo = Backbone.View.extend({
           template: _.template($('#test').html()),
           //...
       });
   });
   ```
2. Don't compile the template until you need it:

   ```
   TodoBb.Views.ComCentersTodo = Backbone.View.extend({
       //... no template in here
       render: function() {
           var html = _.template($('#test').html(), this.model.toJSON());
           this.$el.html(html);
           return this;
       },
       //...
   });
   ```

As a variation of **2**, you could cache the compiled template functions somewhere and only call `_.template($('#test').html())` the first time you use it.